# React-Native-How would I print this array of array of objects in a spreadout format based on a specific key value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I currently have an array of array of objects and wanting to print in a specific format based on each array inside of the master array. Each array basically represents a full order and the objects inside are the order items.

```
Array [
  Array [
    Object {
      "name": "Angela Braun",
      "order_id": 1,
      "price": 39.51,
      "product_id": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "size": "S",
      "status": "placed",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-16 13:36:03",
      "user_id": 2,
    },
  ],
  Array [
    Object {
      "name": "Angela Braun",
      "order_id": 2,
      "price": 39.51,
      "product_id": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "size": "S",
      "status": "placed",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-16 13:36:03",
      "user_id": 2,
    },
    Object {
      "name": "Fred Schmidt",
      "order_id": 2,
      "price": 12.17,
      "product_id": 1,
      "quantity": 1,
      "size": "S",
      "status": "placed",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-16 13:36:03",
      "user_id": 2,
    },
    Object {
      "name": "Margie Legros",
      "order_id": 2,
      "price": 9.48,
      "product_id": 4,
      "quantity": 1,
      "size": "S",
      "status": "placed",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-16 13:36:03",
      "user_id": 2,
    },
  ],
]
```

The format I want is

```
Order 1:
Items
Order 2:
Items
Order 3:
Items
etc.
```

What I've tried:

```
{orders ? 
    orders.map((order, index) => (
      <Text>Order {order[index].order_id}</Text>
      order.map(o => (
        <Text>Name: {o.name} Quantity: {o.quantity}</Text>
      ))
    ))
    : null}
```

The error I get is:

```
')' expected.ts(1005)
```

Which is **referring to the map**. How would I achieve this layout?

Comment: Looks like everything just lives inside `orders[0]`.

Comment: how so? there are 2 arrays inside of the main array that both contain objects

Comment: Well I would start with fixing your syntax error, then see how it prints

Comment: Honestly that's apart of my question. I'm not sure how to achieve a map this way without it throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should straighten you out. You had the following issues: 1) you just need to pull the `order_id` from the first element of the orders array, 2) You need to have a `React.Fragment` parent for the nested map, and 3) You needed to add `{}` around your nested map.

```
{orders && 
  orders.map(order => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Text>Order {order[0].order_id}</Text>
      {order.map(o => (
        <Text>Name: {o.name} Quantity: {o.quantity}</Text>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  ))
}
```